# Binding лини и квадрата

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

Имеется канва на которой я могу рисовать квадраты, а их соединять линиями. Также я могу выделять эти квадраты и перетаскивать как захочу, и соответственно линии также перетягиваются за квадратами. Всё было хорошо, пока я использовал класс `Line`.

Как можно связать через `Binding` один из концов `Polyline` и центр квадрата? У квадрата есть свойства зависимости X и Y и просто свойство CenterPoint.
До этого были связаны квадрат и просто линия - `Line`. Код был таким:

```
public void BindingLineXY2(ref MyLine line)
    {
        Binding bindLX2 = new Binding();
        bindLX2.Source = this;
        bindLX2.Path = new PropertyPath("X");
        bindLX2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        line.MakedLine.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, bindLX2);

        Binding bindLY2 = new Binding();
        bindLY2.Source = this;
        bindLY2.Path = new PropertyPath("Y");
        bindLY2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        line.MakedLine.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, bindLY2);
    }
```

Таким же образом X1 и Y1 биндились.

Решил модернизировать до `Polyline` и столкнулся с трудностями.

Comment: можно узнать почему вы привязываете из кода? разве не удобнее делать это через `xaml`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Не настолько хорошо владею языком разметки. Поэтому мне показалось, что через код будет проще.

Comment: а можете добавить подробностей в вопрос? Пока не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @FoggyFinder добавил информации.

Comment: можно узнать вам подошел ответ?

Comment: К сожалению, нет

Comment: @alladuh что именно не подошло?

Comment: @LunarWhisper Тут я немного некоректен в своём ответе выше. Когда я рисую два квадрата на канве, то потом я могу их соединить линией. Когда они соединены, то я могу их двигать и линия соответственно перемещается за квадратом. Выглядит так, будто они связаны. Чтобы это было проще, я решил связать координаты квадрата и линии. Таким образом, линия всегда тащится за квадратом.
Но когда я решил использовать класс `Polyline`, то сделать привязку для меня стало затруднительно. 
Вот теперь я думаю, может реализация привязки у меня хромает (всё же я только начал программировать)?

Comment: @alladuh вот поэтому и возникает вопрос - в чём проблема? Тебе нужна коллекция точек, к которой может быть привязана `Polyline`, нужна первая и последняя точка для привязки к центру квадратов. Вроде бы, я описал именно то, что тебе нужно. Если у тебя всего две точки (два связанных квадрата), значит коллекция точек будет состоять из двух штук. Правда, непонятно - зачем тогда полилиния.

Comment: @LunarWhisper А если я решу создавать изгибы (изломы) например, чтобы не пересекать линии, думаю лучше использовать Polyline. 
Спасибо за ответ с коллекцией, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `Polyline` есть свойство зависимости [`PointsProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.pointsproperty(v=vs.110).aspx).
Это [коллекция точек](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), к которой ты и можешь привязаться. Положи в неё с нужного тебе края центральную точку квадрата и наслаждайся. Квадрат, соответственно, тоже может быть привязан к точке из этой коллекции. Напрямую, думаю, будет не очень красиво и довольно грязно. Так что лучше через ViewModel с `INotifyPropertyChanged`.